# how to paint points inside or outside a function with python and not just plot them?

Tags: python, paint, pixel

I have a list that represents points, some are inside the area of a function and others aren't. I want to know if I can paint the points as pixels instead of plotting them.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: just add some examples, it's hard to understand what you mean